# BAD VALUE: order_tax_amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, klarna

I'm trying to send request using `Postman` to test `Klarna` payment, According to this [API DOC](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#checkout-api-create-a-new-order), We use `POST /checkout/v3/orders` to send a request so that we can create order (For the testing environment they use `https://api.playground.klarna.com/` + rest of url), But when i'm trying to send the given example in the above link(on the right side), It says that

```
{ "error_code" : "BAD_VALUE", "error_messages" : [ "Bad value: order_tax_amount" ], "correlation_id" : "12255531-ffcb-4a91-a375-04577fca78e5" }
```

When i read what does it require in the [documentation](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#checkout-api__create-a-new-order__order_lines__total_tax_amount), It says that the value should be formatted in some formula `±1 of total_amount - total_amount * 10000 / (10000 + tax_rate)`, When i calculate that the result `4545.4545` when i change the value in the request and try again, It gives the same error.
Can anybody help me with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I should change both `total_tax_amount` and `order_tax_amount` to be `4545`, What a mistake, I think they should update this in their documentation so people be more familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

The docs you've linked say that `order_tax_amount` should be an integer of [minor currency units](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#data-types), so it sounds like `4545.4545` isn't a valid value!

You should choose which direction you want to round in, then send an integer value instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried only 4545 but the same error too, Have you any idea about that?