# BAD VALUE: total_tax_amount

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm trying to send a request using Opencart to test Klarna payment, we can create order (For the testing environment they use https://api.playground.klarna.com/ + rest of URL), But when I'm trying to send request, It says that

```
BAD_VALUE: total_tax_amount
```

I have followed this solution link below
[BAD VALUE: order_tax_amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050138/bad-value-order-tax-amount)

This is my array structure -

```
[order_lines] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => shipping_fee
                [name] => Free freight for orders over 600 Kr
                [quantity] => 1
                [unit_price] => 0
                [tax_rate] => 0
                [total_amount] => 0
                [total_tax_amount] => 0
                [total_discount_amount] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => physical
                [reference] => 239082
                [name] => Tricky Ceiling Light
                [quantity] => 1
                [quantity_unit] => pcs
                [unit_price] => 389900
                [tax_rate] => 2501
                [total_amount] => 389900
                [total_tax_amount] => 78000
                [merchant_data] => 8funuYNjVnsI0TzV-mUCThlZs-NH2SPmZ83oC8HCqU8,
                [total_discount_amount] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type] => physical
                [reference] => 239614
                [name] => Leeds Taklampa Råsilver 38cm
                [quantity] => 1
                [quantity_unit] => pcs
                [unit_price] => 299900
                [tax_rate] => 2501
                [total_amount] => 299900
                [total_tax_amount] => 60000
                [merchant_data] => 8funuYNjVnsI0TzV-mUCThlZs-NH2SPmZ83oC8HCqU8,
                [total_discount_amount] => 0
            )

    )
```

When I send only one product ([name] => **Leeds Taklampa Råsilver 38cm**), it's working fine and created orders But when the two products are sent together, then get this error.

Comment: I have RND and found that there was a problem with the product (Tricky Ceiling Light) total_tax_amount